# Contact Listener Crashes When Box2D body destroyed outside of time step

Tags: box2d

I am using box2d and have bodies that I am destroying out of the world time step (having marked them flagged them for removal) and yet the contact listener is still crashing due to getting contacts that are referencing these bodies.

This is what is done in the presolve and begin contact methods of the contact listener:

```
const b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();

const b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

Object * objectA  = (Object*)bodyA->GetUserData();
Object * objectB  = (Object*)bodyB->GetUserData();
```

Either objectA or objectB are actually pointers to nonsense because the object has been removed (outside of the world time step). Appears that bad contacts are being created or contacts that should no longer exist still do.

**Update**

I have changed the code out of the world step to ensure and validate the correct bodies are being destroyed (as well their container's body) and find that the contact listener is still attempting to processing contacts that should not exist. I happen to be on iOS/Xcode and enable NSZombie and do indeed find the contact body userdata are deallocated objects (message sent to deallocated instance). Checking the Box2d source I find the contacts are indeed destroyed when the body is destroyed. I'll have to go through more Box2D code or just change my code to somehow work around these mysterious contacts the listener receives.

When I test setting the userdata for the body to null (again, outside the world step) the contacts that I receive in the contact listener for this body (when I check it in the contact listener) do not have null userdata.

Comment: How do you destroying the bodies? Show code, please.

Comment: The bodies are destroyed in the proper way (world->DestroyBody(body);). I know the bodies are destroyed, the problem is that the old contacts do not appear to be removed on destroying the body, so these old contacts come through the contact listener and cause issues.

Comment: world->DestroyBody destroys all body contacts. Look there at its code: http://pastebin.com/cKJDfN6c (v2.2.1). I think, you are mix up smth (for example, destroying another body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was creating two identical bodies, unbeknown to me, and passing them both the same userdata. When the first body was destroyed along with the corresponding user data (and containing object) the second one was still creating contact points and since the userdata associated with the body had been freed I was experiencing the problem described.

Setting NULL as the userdata for the body prior to deletion didn't appear to be working because when the crash occurred the debugger was actually showing me the second body which had not had it's user data set to NULL. The reason it took so long for me to find it was because the code had an inheritance structure within the container objects which made it difficult to spot that two bodies were being created.

This turned out to be an error that could not have been solved with just the code I posted so although the answers by Tomasz and Pavel did not lead me to solving the issue I must credit them with for taking the time to at least attempting to help. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see the destruction of the box2d body has nothing to do with all of that. GetUserData returns whatever you passed in when you created the body and that might be garbage. You eater deleted it or you passed in null. If you can provide the code for the creation and the destruction of the bodies I might be able to tell you bit more.

If the body would be invalid then the program would probably crash on:

```
contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
```

or the bodyB part.

Comment: You're right, when the body was created I set the UserData to be the Object containing the body. I.e. the Object class contains a member of b2Body * body. So the body was assigned this Object and that is why the code above is expecting GetUserData() to return an Object object (sorry about  the terrible naming here). That Object was indeed set to be destroyed, in fact the destructor of the object is within which the DestroyBody(body) is done. My issue is that I'm not expecting this contact to be existing anymore because the body and the userdata were deleted outside of the step.

Comment: It might be a daft question, but you are running it in debug mode and you are calling the world->DestroyBody( body ) outside of the box2d world step ? In debug mode if you are trying to call world->DestroyBody( body ) within the contact listener the program should assert, as destroying box2d object is not allowed in world step. In release mode the body would not be removed at all if you try to destroy a body while inside the worlds step. So it would mean that the objects wrapping the box2d body is destroyed and the body and listener is still in the world.

Comment: I am not running in debug mode but the world->DestroyBody(body) is done outside of the world step - it's done right after the world step call and the ClearForces call. If I destroy a body like this from my understanding all of the contacts for that body would be deleted to, could this be a false assumption?

Comment: I am wondering whether the body is not getting destroyed for some reason, but the container object does. I am not in front of the code right now, I will have to check this. Not sure why that would he occur. I should add the problem is sporadic.

Comment: That is a correct assumption to make. Try running it in debug and see if it assert anywhere. The only other thing I can think of is that when you create the objects and the bodies you are passing the wrong objects as the user data, or maybe its destroyed by accident. Without the code I can't help much more beyond that.

Comment: Create a small test bed for the problem and turn on the debug draw for box2D. Then see if the body actually is removed from the world, or put a break point in the b2World.cpp in DestroyBody function just after the first return when locked statement.

Comment: The objects passed in as the user data are correct because they are used just fine in the contact listener prior to the removal attempt of the container object and body. Things only go wrong once the container object is set to be destroyed outside of the world step. I suspect now, thanks to your comments, that the container object does get destroyed but when it calls for the body to be destroyed within its destructor the body does not get destroyed for some reason and the userdata ends up pointing to nonsense. This would explain why these contact points appear in the listener.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I cannot look into this for several hours. However at least I have something to look into now. I do wonder if this is the case, why the body is sometimes not getting destroyed even after calling world->DestroyBody(body).

Comment: Happy to help. 
The only reason I would see is that its destroyed while within the world step, but you say that's not the case. The only other thing would be that the world is set to locked for some reason, but I would not have a clue why that would happen outside of the world step. I'll have a think. Let me know what was the cause when you figure it out.

Comment: The body is not getting deleted. I do not know why, the world is not locked and the destroy is done outside of the world step. Apparently the comments here are getting too long so we should stop discussion for this answer.